# Changing first day of week using GUI in Unity

Tags: unity, calendar, locale

Is there coming possibilty to change the first day of week to be a Monday in GNOME Calender applet using Unity GUI? It's hard to change it now to standard user.

(According to international standard ISO 8601 Sunday is the seventh and last day of the week. = why we don't use standards as default? / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday)

Answer (score 3):

Setting this [at the system level](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet/6457#6457) should also affect the calendar in Unity.

Comment: I have done it, it's not problem to me. It is usability problem to new users and make their first impressions not so good about ubuntu/unity.   Why it's not automatically changed when I select other location than USA (like Estonia in my case)?

Comment: You should file a bug report in this case: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: If I change language to Estonian, then it's working. No need for bug.