# How to change user's language (locale) back to English?

Tags: gnome, locale, language-support

I made the mistake of trying out some settings through Administration -> Language Support. Now my user account has `LANG` set to `fi_FI.utf8`, even though I want to use `en_US.utf8`. (This is kind-of a follow up to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet).)

Listing 1: current locale settings for my user account:

```
$ locale
LANG=fi_FI.utf8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_PAPER=fi_FI.utf8
LC_NAME="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=fi_FI.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Listing 2: /etc/default/locale which contains the locale settings I want to use:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="en_US.utf8"

LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fi_FI.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fi_FI.utf8"
```

The Administration -> Language support settings look like this:

[image]
[image]

My specific questions:

- **Where exactly (in what file) are the user-specific locale settings (listing 1) stored?**
- **What is the recommended way of changing that?** By editing a file or through some config UI? (I want to use the settings in listing 2.)

The root annoyance which prompted me to ask this: How to change Firefox UI language from Finnish back to English?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you want to start a single program in english you can always run it with ALT+F2 (or terminal) using this:
$ `LANG=POSIX firefox`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the language at the login prompt after selecting the user. When asked whether to make the selection the new default, select yes.

Comment: +1, that worked, thanks. (It didn't ask anything about setting default but the selection did seem to persist.) I'm still interested in more details though: whether user's locale can be configured in a file etc.

Comment: The system-locale is stored in */etc/default/locale*. Userspecific locale settings are supposed to go in *~/.profile* by adding something like `LANG=en_EN.utf8`.

Answer (score 6):

The per-user locale default for the Desktop session is stored in `~/.dmrc`. This is the file that is updated when selecting a new locale at the GDM screen. GDM uses this to set up the environment when starting the user's session.

Comment: Thanks. So apparently the GDM selection sets LANG and also fills in any of LC_* with selected locale, except those set in /etc/default/locale. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

If "User Accounts" is crashing each time you start it, you should reset the accounts.

To get the error-message, run 'gnome-control-center' from a terminal and click on "User Accounts". You'll probably see something like this:

```
    (gnome-control-center:5060): common-cc-panel-WARNING **: locale 'xx_XX:nl_NL:en_GB:en
    xx_XX' isn't valid
```

To fix, run the command `gnome-language-selector`. Try changing the locale and language settings to a different one and see if that resolves your problem. Then change back.

Also run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` to see of there are any cache-errors. By purging the bad locales with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure localepurge` you could probably solve the original problem which caused the crashing.

[[source]](http://forum.pinguyos.com/Thread-Problems-opening-user-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Just open terminal and type `sudo gedit` then the text editor will open.
Then open the file `locale` located underneath the `etc/default`.
Then just edit the `LANGUAGE=en` and `LANG="en_US.utf8"`.

Comment: The question is about how to change the user settings. So anything requiring `sudo` is no option.