# How change locale language setting to english in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, locale

My laptop have default setting to my local language. Thus all system configuration like time and date and others showing as this language. Also, it shows language specific number in different system application. But i want to back it as english. How i do this in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11184/how-to-change-users-language-locale-back-to-english?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go `Language Support -> Regional Formats` Tab and then select `English(United States)` from the drop down menu. Finally, click on `Apply System Wide`

After that you need to reboot your laptop and hopefully you will able to see as your expectation!