# Monday as first day in GNOME Shell (instead of Sunday)

Tags: gnome, locale, calendar

I've been dealing with different regional settings (US, Canada and other locations in English, as well as other countries and languages), but I cannot get GNOME Shell Calendar to begin with Monday, instead of Sunday. I have even modified the `en_US` file in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/` (line: first workday: 1). All without success. My question is: is it hard-coded in GNOME Shell or it can be changed?

Answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet) previous question doesn't apply to GNOME Shell.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Monday as the first day of the week in GNOME Calendar applet?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet)

Comment: @Anwar That's not a duplicate, as that question is asking about the calendar applet in GNOME 2, whereas this question is asking about GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To adjust this, change or add the following lines in the `LC_TIME` section in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/<your_locale>`:

```
week            7;19971130;5
first_weekday   2
first_workday   2
```

(`first_weekday 2` sets Monday as the first day of the week, and `first_workday 2` sets Monday as the first work day of the week.)

And then update the system:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

Then log out and log in again.

Comment: I made this change on my system, but it seems to have gotten wiped after an upgrade. To avoid that, I ended up making my own locale file, putting it in `/usr/local/share/i18n/locales/`, then running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. It was quite a process and there's a bunch more setup I haven't mentioned here. If anyone knows an easier way, I'm all ears.

Comment: I did that on Ubuntu 22 and it doesn't work. In `/usr/share/i18n/locales/fr_BE` I've set the same params as this post. In `/etc/default/locale` I have `LC_TIME=fr_BE.UTF-8`. I've updated the system and logged out. In the applet the week still starts on Sunday.