# How to make week in calendar start on Sunday on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, calendar, japanese

As a part of me learning Japanese I want to eventually make my computer completely in Japanese, however there is one problem, in all the Japanese calendars I have the week starts on Sunday as opposed to Monday, however even when changing the language of the calendar (the built-in one accessible through the top-bar), the week still is displayed as starting on Monday. I am sure that I have seen an option to change this before, I just can't seem to find it now, but maybe I saw that option on another DE.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, how can I set it so that the built-in calendar shows the week starting from Sunday?

Comment: Duplicates http://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet http://askubuntu.com/questions/197613/monday-as-first-day-in-gnome-shell-instead-of-sunday