# How to make calendar points to Sunday as first day of the week in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, calendar

Everyone is asking how to make Monday the first day of the week,
here I am stuck with it unable to change it.

I tried already changing the lines in `/usr/share/i18n` files but no luck and doesn't seem to change anything.

[image: gnome system calendar]

Comment: Your language settings can have an effect on this too. Type `locale` from the command line and look for `LC_TIME` what does it say?

Comment: LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8

Answer (score 7):

A similar question was asked here: [Monday as first day in Gnome-Shell (instead of Sunday)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197613/monday-as-first-day-in-gnome-shell-instead-of-sunday).

1. Use `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB`.
2. Edit the value of `first_weekday` to `1`.
3. Save the file, restart the system.

There is a second variable: `first_workday` that is set to `2`. Some calendar's may refer to this variable but I would initially leave it unchanged unless further tweaking is needed.

Essentially you will make your `GB` locale look like the `US` locale:

```
$ cat /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB | grep week -A1
week    7;19971130;4
first_weekday 2
first_workday 2

$ cat /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US | grep week -A1
week    7;19971130;7
first_weekday   1
first_workday   2
```

I don't know what the `week` variable does so would leave it unchanged at first.

Comment: i already tried all that, when i first tried this back in ubunto17.10 it worked, but now it seems that the changes i make are completely ignored in the i18n files.

Comment: In this case I would find it better to advise users to use the possibility to add (potentially copied and modified) own locales to `/usr/local/share/i18n/locales`, as documented in `/usr/share/doc/locales/README.Debian`

Comment: set the region to Canada en_CA for now, but i would like to have my own with tiny tweaks to it

Comment: I'm also using region `en_CA` and have dual needs between US and GB. For example I prefer US date format but prefer GB spelling. Is the first day of week working as required now? Do you think the tweaks you need are better asked a new question or will you update your existing question with those needed tweaks instead?

Comment: dead link in the answer.

Comment: @joker Thanks. I've updated the link.

Comment: `man 5 locale` describes the meaning of each attribute. For the week, it is  " a list of three values separated by semicolons: The number of days in a week (by default 7), a date of beginning of the week (by default corresponds to Sunday), and the minimal length of the first week in year (by default  4).  Regarding the start of the week, 19971130 shall be used for Sunday and 19971201 shall be used for Monday".

Comment: I think you need to run `sudo locale-gen` after editing the file.

Comment: @hnagaty It might be worth mentioning (to prevent people from directly modifying `week`) that `man 5 locale` also states: "For compatibility reasons, all glibc locales should set the value of the second week list item to 19971130 (Sunday) and base the abday and  day  lists  appropriately,  and  set  first_weekday  and first_workday to 1 or 2, depending on whether the week and work week actually starts on Sunday or Monday for the locale."

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with changing the first day of the week for the Australian locale (en_AU); I wanted to change the first day of the week from Sunday to Monday. However, the locale file did not make any reference to "first_weekday". I got the desired change I wanted by:

- opening this file for edits as as super user `sudo gedit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_AU`
- adding the line `first_weekday 2` to the section of this file labelled "LC_TIME"
- Updating the system locale information `sudo locale-gen`
- Logging out and logging in again.

Comment: Cheers! I avoided having to re-login by reloading Gnome using: Alt+F2, r, Enter

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 22.04. I wanted Sunday as first day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it's the first google result when searching for this issue.

There's no need to change files outside your home folder. Just add `LC_TIME=en_US.utf8` to your profile file:

```bash
echo "export LC_TIME=en_US.utf8" >> ~/.profile
```

You'll need to login again for it to take effect.

Modifying configs outside your home folder makes it harder to transfer them to a new machine or a new OS install.