# Change first day of the week does not work

Tags: 16.04, locale, calendar

I tried to follow the instructions on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6016/how-to-set-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-gnome-calendar-applet), but it did not work for me, what I'm doing wrong?
Here's my local file in /etc/default/locale

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Did you log out and log back in?

Comment: Yes, I did, to double check, I even turned off the pc then back on, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

- To find out, which locale file is Ubuntu using right now:

  `locale`

The output in my case:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

That means, that my locale is **en_US**, settings for this locale are saved in file `en_us` in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/` directory.

- Make a backup of the file:
  `sudo cp /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US.bak`
- Edit the en_US file and change first_weekday from 1 (Sunday) to 2
  (Monday):
  `sudo nano /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`
- Then generate locale files:
  `sudo locale-gen`
- Login and logout to apply changes:
  `gnome-session-quit`

**Credits:** [Change first day of week to Monday on Ubuntu GNOME calendar](http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/gnome/change-first-day-of-week-to-monday-on-ubuntu-gnome-calendar)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. Just curious, why by changing to LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" did not work? It seems overwritten somehow.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. **I am not sure** but I think the configuration file has been changed: in the old version, just changing LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" would do the thing, but in the new version, the structure of the file has been changed so , may be, changing that line would not have an effect.