# Gnome Calendar 3.36.2 - no preferences

Tags: gnome, calendar, gnome-calendar

Using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome Calendar 3.36.2 installed from default repositories with `apt`.

There don't seem to be any UI preferences?
e.g. to set the start-end days of the week, work hours etc.

I just have this at the menubar and they don't take me anywhere with preferences, and nothing in the Ubuntu top-bar either. Didn't see anything in dconf either

[image: gnome-calendar screenshot]

Do these settings not exist any more, or did they never exist?

Comment: anything in [this old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/6457/307670) which helps? What options exist under the hamburger menu? (I don't use GNOME calendar but Google instead).

Comment: No that seems limited to things that are controlled by locale (language, date format etc). None of those will restrict the view to certain days/hours.

Hamburger menu just has Online Accounts, Weather, Keyboard Shortcuts and About.